# discord.js - How to pick random users from reactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to pick a random user from the people who reacted

When I run it it says "message.guild.members.random is not a function"

What is the correct way to get a random user? Thanks!

```js
bot.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
  let msg = reaction.message,
    emoji = reaction.emoji;
  if (emoji.name == "❎" && user == message.author) {
    let winner = message.guild.members.random().user.id;

    message.channel.send(
      "Congraulations! <@" +
        winner +
        "> won " +
        prize +
        "\nDM <@" +
        per +
        "> to claim your prize.",
    );
  }
  if (reaction.partial) {
    try {
      await reaction.fetch();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error: ", error);
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[the answer lays here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch)

the guild.members returns you a GuildManager class, which then you can use the fetch() method to fetch all of these guild members:

```
let guildMembers = await message.guild.members.fetch()
// now you can randomly get a memeber through Math.random function
let winner = guildMembers[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(guildMembers.length)).user.id
```

Comment: There is no need for flooring the `guildMembers.length` it will be an integer. Simplify to `Math.floor(Math.random() * guildMembers.length)`, also you forgot the end bracket.

Comment: @Karizma I still get a type error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined." What is the problem here?

Comment: It means it couldn't find a member with that random number, which makes since sense its a collection mapped by ids. I've added an answer

Answer (score 0):

First error: you are using partials which is v12, and you are using `message.guild.members` as a collection which is v11.

Second possible error: you are comparing two objects, `user` and `msg.author`, these might not be the same reference so you should prob just check their id's instead, `user.id === msg.author.id`

Assuming you update to v12:

Since you are using partials it might be that the guild isn't complete, move up the if statement of reaction.partial.

```js
if (reaction.partial) {
    try {
      await reaction.fetch();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error: ", error);
      return;
    }
}
```

Since partials are new and I haven't used them much, I'm not sure if `reaction.message` could be a partial. So you might wanna also fetch that.

After that you have to change

`message.guild.members` => `message.guild.members.cache`

Then you can use `.random`

note: you don't have to convert it into a user to get the id, you can just do

`let winner = message.guild.members.cache.random().id`

Also you can simplify the message you send by either:

```js
message.channel.send(`Congratulations! <@${winner}> won ${prize} \nDM <@${per}> to claim your prize`);
```

or

```js
let winner = message.guild.members.cache.random().user;
message.channel.send(`Congratulations! ${winner} won ${prize} \nDM <@${per}> to claim your prize`);
```

Future errors:

you are allowing any user to have this functionality, since you don't have a check for mod role/perm